# Quarkus and duplicate liquibase master file

Tags: liquibase, quarkus

I've just moved up to Quarkus 2.11.1.Final from 2.6.2.Final and my native image is now failing to start up with the error:

```
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.323 BST2022-07-29 14:53:36,275 WARN [io.qua.ope.run.tra.LateBoundSampler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) No Sampler delegate specified, no action taken.
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.361 BST2022-07-29 14:53:36,361 INFO [io.qua.sma.ope.run.OpenApiRecorder] (main) Default CORS properties will be used, please use 'quarkus.http.cors' properties instead
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.398 BST2022-07-29 14:53:36,398 INFO [liq.database] (main) Set default schema name to public
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.432 BST2022-07-29 14:53:36,432 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.io.IOException: Found 2 files with the path 'db/changelog/liquibase-changelog-master.yml':
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.432 BST - resource:/db/changelog/liquibase-changelog-master.yml
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.432 BST - resource:/db/changelog/liquibase-changelog-master.yml#1
Info
2022-07-29 15:53:36.432 BST Search Path:
```

I tried altering `quarkus.liquibase.change-log` to something very specific just in case it was picking a file of the same name from some 3rd party, but it doesn't make any difference.

Could this be a bug, or could I have missed something in uprevving Quarkus?

Comment: I think I figured it out; in older versions of Quarkus it was necessary to set `quarkus.native.resources.include` to ensure that additional liquibase change files were present in the native image. That seems to be done automatically now so including them in that property resulted in duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Answer posted as a comment by @wabrit

> in older versions of Quarkus it was necessary to set quarkus.native.resources.include to ensure that additional liquibase change files were present in the native image. That seems to be done automatically now so including them in that property resulted in duplicates